# How can I convert type var to object of Customer class

Tags: c#

```
public class Customer
{
    private int customerId;
    private string contactTitle;
    private string country;
    private string contactName;
}

var customer = db.From<Customer>().Where(c => c.CustomerId == Customer.CustomerId).Select();
Customer cc = (Customer)customer;
// it is error i can't convert to object of class Customer
```

Comment: You should include the error message.

Comment: Assuming you are using Visual Studio, you can hover your mouse over customer and see the type of `customer`.

Comment: You should always post the full and exact error message you're getting. In this case the error message will state what you're trying to convert **from** and this is important for this question.

Comment: The title of their question points out that they don't entirely understand what `var` does. Don't see how an error message stating that you can't cast one type to another is going to help anyone explain that to them.

Comment: The `Select` won´t even compile, so the actual problem is neither rerlated to casting nor to `var`.

Answer (score 3):

**var keyword**

This keyword implicitly figures out what the type of the variable is based on its value. That is why something like `var test = null;` won't compile, because it doesn't know what type null is supposed to be (since any object can be null). More info on the [var](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx) keyword.

**Selecting the Customer**

Clearly, based on your code you want to select the customer with the given CustomerId. To do this,

```
var customer = db.From<Customer>().SingleOrDefault(c => c.CustomerId == Customer.CustomerId);
```

Technically, `FirstOrDefault` will also work. The difference is *mostly* symantical, use `FirstOrDefault` when you want the first of many. Use `SingleOrDefault` when you expect one and only one result.

Answer (score 1):

If you would examine your error you would see that it probably says something like: "Can not convert from IEnumerable to Costumer".

That is because the `Where` in your LinQ return a collection of Costumers even if it is only one Costumer it is still a collection.

Instead of `Where` try `First` or `Single` or if there is a possibility that the database would return null use `FirstOrDefault` or `SingleOrDefault`

```
var customer = db.From<Customer>().First(c => c.CustomerId == Customer.CustomerId);    
var customer = db.From<Customer>().Single(c => c.CustomerId == Customer.CustomerId);
var customer = db.From<Customer>().SingleOrDefault(c => c.CustomerId == Customer.CustomerId);
var customer = db.From<Customer>().FirstOrDefault(c => c.CustomerId == Customer.CustomerId);
```

By using one of these options you don't need to cast it afterwards from var to Customer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, var is not a type, its more of a strongly typed placeholder for the type of the first thing you put into it. In this case an IEnumerable of customers or IQueryable.

You can fix this by changing:

```
var customer = db.From().Where(c => c.CustomerId == Customer.CustomerId).Select();
```

which will return an enumerable to:

```
var customer = db.From().Where(c => c.CustomerId == Customer.CustomerId).SingleOrDefault();
```

Then var hold a customer object.

Comment: "which will return an enumerable to" The `Select` as you wrote won´t even compile, so it doesn´t return *anything*.

Comment: how can i convert var result to ObservableCollection<Customer>          var result = db.From<Customer>().Select(c =>
                  new
                  {
                      CustomerId = Customer.CustomerId,

                      CompanyId = Customer.CompanyName,
                      ContactName = Customer.ContactName,
                      ContactTitle = Customer.ContactTitle
                  });

                Customers = new ObservableCollection<Customer>(result);

Comment: `Select()` manipulates each item in the result set. So your code above is taking every single customer from your database and making a new anonymous object from it. Therefore returning a collection of anonymous objects. If you want just one, use `SingleOrDefault` or `FirstOrDefault`. As suggested a couple of the answers above.

Answer (score 0):

because you select `customer` collection

You can use [First()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976(v=vs.100).aspx) for select first customer in accordance with conditions

```
var customer = db.From<Customer>().Where(c => c.CustomerId == Customer.CustomerId).First();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need single object, you should be using `FirstOrDefault()` after `Where()`:

```
Customer customer = db.From<Customer>()
                      .Where(c => c.CustomerId == Customer.CustomerId)
                      .FirstOrDefault();
```

It will make sure that if no record is return your code will not blow out throwing exception.